# Recently installed Microsoft Speech voices not available

Tags: c#, text-to-speech, speech, microsoft-speech-platform, system.speech.recognition

I have installed the Microsoft Speech Platform runtime from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225 and some runtime languages from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27224, but when I try to check the installed languages through an application only the default ones will appear.

I add the System.Speech reference and create a synthesizer then do this:

```
foreach (var v in synth.GetInstalledVoices().Select(v => v.VoiceInfo))
{
 s = "Name:" + v.Description.ToString() + ", Gender:" + v.Gender.ToString() + ", Age:" + v.Age.ToString();
 MessageBox.Show(s);
 }
```

I have read that `Microsoft.Speech` and `System.Speech` are different things, with the first one being focused on server applications and the latter on desktop applications.

I am trying to develop a desktop application, hence using the `System.Speech` reference, but the only languages I see available for download are Microsoft Speech languages. I have tried this on both Windows 7 and 8.1. I only need the TTS function, not SR.

So long story short, how do I add another language to work with TTS on `System.Speech`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the speech platform has it's own registry keys for their voices. Check out my answer here [how to change your registry keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167967/python-3-4-text-to-speech-with-sapi)

It's a hack for sure, but it'll get you the answer you want.

*disclaimer - this would have been a comment instead of an answer had my reputation exceeded 50*