# How to add new voices to Windows to use in System.Speech.Synthesis?

Tags: c#, sapi, speech-synthesis

Calling this API:

```
        using System.Speech.Synthesis;

        foreach (InstalledVoice voice in synth.GetInstalledVoices())
        {
            VoiceInfo info = voice.VoiceInfo;

            Debug.WriteLine(" Name:          " + info.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(" Culture:       " + info.Culture);
            Debug.WriteLine(" Age:           " + info.Age);
            Debug.WriteLine(" Gender:        " + info.Gender);
            Debug.WriteLine(" Description:   " + info.Description);
            Debug.WriteLine(" ID:            " + info.Id);
        }
```

Returns:

```
Name:          Microsoft Anna
Culture:       en-US
Age:           Adult
Gender:        Female
Description:   Microsoft Anna - English (United States)
ID:            MS-Anna-1033-20-DSK
```

How can I add more voices to the system? I have tried installing SAPI5 and SAPI4 voices from this link: http://biblprog.com/en/speech_api/voices_sapi/

But they do not appear in the list.

I have gone into the "Text to Speech" tab in "Speech Properties" control panel and also only Anna appears on the list. Not sure why this is hard.

I am using Windows 7 64 bit OS. Any ideas?

I just want to understand how to add new voices. As I want to purchase one from here http://www.textaloud.com/englishaustralian.shtml but want to make sure it will work ok.

Comment: I think it didn't installed properly, since you couldn't find them at the control panel.

Comment: There's a hacky way of getting Speech Platform voices to work that I listed here on SO a while ago that you might find useful. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167967/python-3-4-text-to-speech-with-sapi/31172101#31172101)

Answer (score 0):

SAPI voices have code, along with voice data.  So it matters whether the voices are 32 or 64 bit.   I suspect that the voices you initially downloaded are 32 bit voices, and don't show up in the 64 bit control panel.

You can double-check this by making sure that your program is compiled as ["Any CPU 32 bit Preferred"](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-4-5-and-visual-studio-11.aspx) (or x86 if your version of visual studio doesn't support that).