# python text translation to speech

Tags: python, text-to-speech, google-translate, sapi

I am working on testing text translation 
(from English to other language) and translation to audio code using python. I am using google translate api for translation and win32 for audio.
While testing i found that google supports https://gist.github.com/jseabold/1473363 these languages. The translation part of code seem to be working fine for many options but audio part only works with a few languages (english , spanish , italian etc works).

as you can see in example below I can see text is translated into Hindi correctly but i get no audio output.  I feel that `wincl.dispatch` is not supporting all languages as google translate. furthurmore i could not find details on win32 api regarding supported languages. can you help me finding this list or in engilsh text to hindi audio solution?

thanks

```
from googletrans import Translator
import win32com.client as wincl
translator = Translator()



a=translator.translate('안녕하세요.')
a=translator.translate('I am robot',src='en',dest='hi')
print (a.text)
speak = wincl.Dispatch("SAPI.SpVoice")
speak.Speak(a.text)


मैं रोबोट हूँ

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: a quick google search found the following SAPI supported languages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech/api-reference-rest/supportedlanguages


you can follow a tutorial here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms720163(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks @castaway2000 it did some help. I am more comfortable with python so I am still in hunt of pythonic way to configuring  SAPI output

Comment: I would encourage you to learn how to read code not just read python. this way a lot of tutorials can be useful to you regardless of programming language.

Answer (score 0):

SAPI only supports voices that are installed.   Since Microsoft doesn't have a Hindi TTS voice, you will need to look elsewhere for either a SAPI-compliant Hindi TTS voice, or a web service that supports Hindi TTS.   A web search will help you with your selection.